# NullPointerException: EditText in DialogAlert

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dialog, android-edittext

I got a `NullPointerException` using an `EditText` in a `DialogAlert`. My code looks like this:

```
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WelcomeDialog();
        }

            public Dialog WelcomeDialog() {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setTitle("Server");
                builder.setMessage("Enter ADDRESS and PORT:");
                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_welcome, null);
                builder.setView(v);
                // Use an EditText view to get user input.
                final EditText input1 = new EditText(this);
                input1.setId(address);
                builder.setView(input1);
                final EditText ETaddress = (EditText) v.findViewById(address);

                final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
                input2.setId(port);
                builder.setView(input2);
                final EditText ETport = (EditText) v.findViewById(port);
                builder.setView(v)
                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                        // Add action buttons
                        .setPositiveButton("connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // The NULLPOINTER is in this line:
                                String str1 = ETaddress.getText().toString();
                                ((VariableHolder) getApplication()).setADDRESS(str1);
                                int str2 = Integer.parseInt(ETport.getText().toString());
                                ((VariableHolder) getApplication()).setPORT(str2);
                                set = true;

                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
                return builder.create();
            }
      }
}
```

I suspect that the problem is here (wrong declaration or something like that):

```
            final EditText input1 = new EditText(this);
            input1.setId(address);
            builder.setView(input1);
            final EditText ETaddress = (EditText) v.findViewById(address);
```

...but I can't figure it out whats wrong. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Here is the logcat Output:

```
> 01-06 19:40:28.241    4694-4694/com.example.console2
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.example.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:88)
>             at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4611)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat error trace?

Comment: add crash log please.

Comment: Why are you using `builder.setView()` method so many times??

Comment: That v view doesn't contain your edittext. v.findViewById(address) this will return null only.

Comment: Need A Logcat because null might be in every place of your code,i think its on your edit text phase,just post log cat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, that was a stupid mistake. Only forgot `R.id` before address respectively port:

```
final EditText ETaddress = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.address); // R.id. !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

That v view doesn't contain your edittext so **v.findViewById(address)** will return null only.

Try this,

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/

Answer (score 1):

if your suspecting that problem in that,do the next!
1 Remove final modifiers all of them!
2 Find their view after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` like this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     EditText input1 = new (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
     EditText ETaddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
```

and do the rest!

Comment: Can you see he is creating `input1` at runtime and extracting `ETaddress` from another view using inflater? Your answer doesn't help. Also removing final won't prevent crashing in fact he won't be able to use that in listeners method. Reason is something different and we can't say anything without seeing the logcat error trace.

Comment: yes sure its wrong thats why i posted this code,he just needs to find views FIRSTLY then do his things